# Recharts bar chart aligns bars incorrectly

Tags: reactjs, recharts

Currently my bar chart looks like this:
[image]

For Jobs and Areas, I want the bars centered above the label (just like Machines). Is this possible? This is my code: [codeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bar-graph-with-categories-u06ppv?file=/src/App.tsx)